# Batch insert and arithmetic subtraction Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I have this function that doesn't batch insert to my database, I only used the batch insert function recently because back then I only used object inserts through for loops like this

```
$subject = ActiveCurriculum::find()
    ->select('scstock.*')
    ->joinWith('schead')
    ->where(['schead.TrNo' => $TrNo])
    ->one();

$activesubject              = new ActiveSubject();
$activesubject->clientid    = $clientid;
$activesubject->TrNo        = $subject->TrNo;
$activesubject->LINE        = $subject->LINE;
$activesubject->period      = $subject->schead->period;
$activesubject->subjectcode = $subject->subjectcode;
$activesubject->schedday    = $subject->schedday;
$activesubject->schedtime   = $subject->schedtime;
//remember to use schead if the value is joined from another table.
$activesubject->section  = $subject->schead->section;
$activesubject->roomcode = $subject->roomcode;
$activesubject->units    = $subject->units;
$activesubject->save();

//reduces the slot of ccsubject by 1
$subject->slots = $subject->slots - 1;
//never forget the saving part
$subject->save();
```

I am not able to use this this time because I needed to insert an array of values so as I said I opted to this.

```
$subjects = ActiveCurriculum::find()
    ->select(['scstock.*', 'schead.*'])
    ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
    ->where(['sectiongroup' => $group])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();


// $activesubject  = new ActiveSubject();
$bulkInsertArray = [];
foreach ($subjects as $values) {

    $bulkInserArray[] = [
        'clientid'    => $clientid,
        'TrNo'        => $values['TrNo'],
        'LINE'        => $values['LINE'],
        'period'      => $values['period'],
        'subjectcode' => $values['subjectcode'],
        'schedday'    => $values['schedday'],
        'schedtime'   => $values['schedtime'],
        'section'     => $values['section'],
        'roomcode'    => $values['roomcode'],
        'units'       => $values['units'],
    ];

    if (count($bulkInsertArray) > 0) {

        $columnNameArray = ['clientid', 'TrNo', 'LINE', 'period', 'subjectcode', 'schedday', 'schedtime', 'section', 'roomcode', 'units'];

        // below line insert all your record and return number of rows inserted
        $insertCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->batchInsert('subjectcontainer', $columnNameArray, $bulkInsertArray)
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

But I am not able to

```
 $subject->slots = $subject->slots - 1;
 $subject->save();
```

like in the first one because of the arrays, can you tell me how to do this in my second code because I need to subtract the slots column by 1 every iteration of the for loop this time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform subtraction using single query. Something like this:

```
$columnToUpdate = ['slots' => new \yii\db\Expression('[[slots]] - 1')];
$condition      = ['sectiongroup' => $group];

ActiveCurriculum::updateAll( $columnToUpdate, $condition );
```

It will execute SQL:

```
UPDATE `active_curriculum` SET `slots`=`slots` - 1 WHERE `sectiongroup`=1234
```

You just need to make correct condition that correctly selects necessary rows. Alternatively, you can collect primary keys of records (IDs) when you prepare `$bulkInserArray` and use them for condition:

```
$condition = ['id' => $subjectIDsToUpdate];
```

This condition will build `id IN (...)` automatically.